Custom labels lost while backfilling Prometheus
I am trying to backfill Prometheus with openmetrics data file using "tsdb promtool create-blocks-from openmetrics". My file has custom labels associated with few matrics. But, after backfilling, I am not able to view those metrics.
Any guidance would be valuable.
Thank you
I can see the custom labels when I view the prometheus instance which is configured to have these labels. But when I backfill it to another instance, I cant view that anymore.
